# How to maintain consistency between Azure blob storage and Mongo db

Tags: mongodb, azure, nosql, azure-blob-storage, solid-principles

I have Images saved frequently in an azure blob storage
and then some meta data for each image are saved in a mongo db.
How to maintain an atomic transaction ensuring that the 2 storages are always synced and valid.

I know I can make it manually but I think there should be a more clean way to ensure an atomic transaction and keeping both storages always synced.

Comment: I think you can use Azure function with blob trigger to add/delete data operation in mongo db when an image is uploaded/removed in storage.Details see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp

Comment: I think it could be helpful but in my case there is lots of data with the image needs to be saved in the mongodb after the upload is completed, so triggering the function wont have access to these data.